# Combining HttpSession with EJb

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle httpsession in combination with pure EJB web services. I have created a utility class and I have a controller class. Where is the best place to instantiate a utility class inside the controller class? The plan is that each user that visits/calls a webservice i.e. using the website the first time should have a httpsession object assigned to them:

```
public class Utility {

@Resource
private WebServiceContext wsContext;

public MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();

public HttpSession getSession(){
    return ((HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT)).getSession(true);
}
}

@Path("controller")
@Stateless
public class ControllerEJB {

@POST
public void registerUser(
        @QueryParam("fornamn") String fornamn,
        @QueryParam("efternamn") String efternamn,
        @QueryParam("epost") String epost,
        @QueryParam("epost2") String epost2,
        @QueryParam("password") String password
){

    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(epost);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.setFornamn(fornamn);
    user.setEfternamn(efternamn);
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String firstMethod(){
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail("sam.gholizadeh");
    return "unfisnihedmethod";
}
}
```

I've followed this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13734/stateful.htm but as metioned earlier I'm not sure how and where to implement the logic that keeps track if a visitor has been assigned a session id or not.

Edit: Should the controller class be stateful or stateless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using JAX-RS, it's even easier to directly get the `HttpServletRequest` using JAX-RS:

```
@Path("controller")
@Stateless
public class ControllerEJB {


    @POST
    public void registerUser(
           @QueryParam("fornamn") String fornamn,
           @QueryParam("efternamn") String efternamn,
           @QueryParam("epost") String epost,
           @QueryParam("epost2") String epost2,
           @QueryParam("password") String password,
           @Context HttpServletRequest request){

           HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

           ...

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you know! Thanks. Going to try it.